# Async Node JS query connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, async.js

I am trying to create a excel workbook using excelbuilder and populating the data with information from a mysql database. This is my get method:

```
 app.get('/excel', function(req, res) {

var locationSpread = ['location1.xlsx', 'location2.xlsx', 
'location3.xlsx'];

locationSpread.forEach(function(filename) {
 fs.unlink("./Spreadsheets/" + filename, (err) => {
   if (err) {
     console.log('Spreadsheet ' + filename + ' not found');
   } else {
     console.log('Spreadsheet ' + filename + ' successfully found');
   }
 });

 var query = connection.query('SELECT * from ' + filename.slice(0, -5), function(err, rows) {

   var workbook = excelbuilder.createWorkbook('./Spreadsheets/', filename);
   var sheet = workbook.createSheet(filename.slice(0, -5), 3, rows.length);
   sheet.set(1, 1, 'First Name');
   sheet.set(2, 1, 'Last Name');
   sheet.set(3, 1, 'Company');

   *** TROUBLE CODE START HERE ***
   for (var j = 2, z = 0; z < rows.length; j++, z++) {
     sheet.set(1, j, rows[z].firstName);
     sheet.set(2, j, rows[z].lastName);
     sheet.set(3, j, rows[z].company);
   }
   *** TROUBLE CODE END HERE ***

   workbook.save(function(err) {
     console.log('workbook saved ' + (err ? 'failed' : 'ok'));
   });
 });
 });
 });
```

The first thing I do is delete the files if they exist in the folder Spreadsheets. Then I query the database based on the location. I create a new workbook and sheet then write to it. The for loop breaks the program and while the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

I believe it to be something along the lines of async

Comment: Where do you use Async? Are you sure it is not the line `sheet.set(1, ...` the cause of the error? Can you post the calling stack of the exception?

Comment: The error can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/gKpBvUQx

But essentially if I were to run this code without the for loop inside, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fault I see here is that you're using the async version of `unlink`. Potentially, if the file was not deleted when you try to create the work book, an error may occur.

You can try switching to `unlinkSync` and verifying that the `workbook` object is not null before creating a sheet (and as additional precaution, that the `sheet` object is not null before setting values).

Beyond that, it's impossible to assist further without your error stack.

Comment: Changing to unlinkSync caused the application error outputting a Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink

So I don' think that caused the error since unlink actually worked and caught the error when it was thrown.

The error can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/gKpBvUQx

But essentially if I were to run this code without the for loop inside, it works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, that might be your root cause: `unlinkSync` does exactly the same as `unlink`. If it fails deleting the file, it means the file is not there. Check if it's there before attempting to delete.

Answer (score 0):

So the error was because of an error of an initial setup. Basically the createWorkbook has an initial number of rows and columns and if you happen to try and write a value that goes out of the bounds of what you initially created, it throws an error. Hence, why my for loop kept on crashing.